# How to sort by date with Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets, sorting, regex

Consider the following text in a single column in a spreadsheet:

```
AAPL 2015 Dec 18 C @ 185.000
AAPL 2016 Mar 18 C @ 160.000
...
```

How to sort by date?

I tried extracting the date using regex, but it is a lot of work to convert that to a date object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extracting the date with regex, and converting the result with `datevalue` isn't *that* much work:

```
=datevalue(regexreplace(A2, "^\w* (\d+) (\w+) (\d+).*", "$1-$2-$3"))
```

Then sort by this new column.

Explanation: the three captured groups in the regex are the year, month, and day. The whole string gets replaced by year-month-day, which isn't quite ISO standard (month is in text) but is clear enough for `datevalue` to convert correctly.

Comment: It's easy when you know how to do it! Actually, I thought it wasn't parsing because the date is displayed as the epoch.

Comment: Ah yes, if the column with the formula is not formatted as Date, it will show up as a day count.

Comment: Oh, so that's the trick. Thanks.